# How do I find a list of words in a sentence where each word might be separated by n other words

Tags: python

I have a list of words i.e. `"please find cat"`
and I have a sentence "can you **please** **find** my pretty **cat**"
and I have variable indicating the number of words that can be between the "list" of words that determine if this is a match.

For this example, if the fuzziness value between the words was 2 or more, the answer would be `true`. If it was 1 or less then the answer would be `false`.

The 'fuzziness' variable can be used between any word. With a fuzzy value of 2 "**please** hello bob **find** my pretty **cat**". This would be `true`

The order matters, if the sentence was "**find** **please** my pretty **cat**". That would be `false`.

I'm making the presumption that there is a library in Python that I can uses. If not, then I was looking at regular expressions. Neither of which I've been able to find. Everything I've seen returns true if all the words are in the sentence, regardless of the gap between them.

Comment: 2 or above ? There is no word between *please* and *find*, so ?

Comment: does order of the words matters? what about the sentence "find his little cat please".

Comment: @NathanHardy yes order does matter. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small script, I hope I understood your problem:

```
import numpy as np

def check(text, sentence, n):
    index = []
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word in text.split(" "):
            i = sentence.split(" ").index(word)
            print("Word '"+word+"' found in sentence in position "+str(i+1)+".")
            index.append(i+1)
            #i+1 to make it more understandable
    #print(index)
    #print(np.diff(index))
    if any(t>(n+1) for t in np.diff(index)):
        # If there are n words between the words we are looking for, then the difference between words position should be n+1
        # E.g. First word is in position 2 and second is in position 6, there are 3 words between and 6-3=4=(3+1)
        print("No match found")
        return False
    else:
        print("Match found")
        return True
```

Examples:

```
text = "please find cat"
sentence = "can you please find my pretty cat"
n = 2
check(text,sentence,n) #True

n = 1
check(text,sentence,n) #False

n = 3 
check(text,sentence,n) #True
```

```
text = "please find cat"
sentence = "can you please find my pretty little cat"
n = 2
check(text,sentence,n) #False

n = 3
check(text,sentence,n) #True
```

Comment: Hi @iserranoe. I recreated this, but the test fails. In this example n = 2 and 3 is greater than 2; so t<n from if all (t<n for t in np.diff(index)) fails

Comment: You are right, it's not working. I changed the code and it should work now.

Comment: I see now, you updated the question and order matters, this doesn't work with order. I'll think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
sentence = 'please find cat'
question = 'can you please find my pretty cat'
SENTENCE = sentence.split(' ')
QUESTION = question.split(' ')

sum(x in SENTENCE for x in QUESTION)
```

Comment: Thats is not at all, what the question asks ;)

Comment: I guess you suggest the number of words from a sentence, which are present in a question. The author asked for the distance between the words from the ``sentence`` in the ``question``.

Comment: Sorry, my poor english made me misunderstood. I thought it was the number of words in common

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any builtin function doing this. re can help but I don't think it's necessary, and not a good idea either.

The old function I wrote here was wrong. What about this backtrack algorithm

```py
def check_splitable(words_as_string, sentence, max_word_between):
  kw = words_as_string.split(' ')
  sw = sentence.split(' ')
  mx = max_word_between

  def _check_splitable(ki, si):
    if (ki >= len(kw)):
      # has come to last keyword,
      #   just check how many words rest in the sentence
      return len(sw) - si <= mx
    for i in range(mx + 1):
      if sw[si + i] == kw[ki]:
        if _check_splitable(ki + 1, si + i + 1):
          return True
    return False

  return _check_splitable(0, 0)

was = 'please find cat'
sen = 'can you please find your cat'
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 3) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 2) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 1) is False

sen = 'find your pretty cat please'
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 3) is False
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 2) is False
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 1) is False

sen = 'please a find find a a cat'
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 3) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 2) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 1) is False

sen = 'can you please find your cat thank you'
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 3) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 2) is True
assert check_splitable(was, sen, 1) is False
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks great.

Comment: Please be careful @JiminyJames , I believe this code has some issues, if I understand your problem -

Comment: ```# Should be True, because maximum words between 'find' and 'cat'
# is just one 'your'.
print(check_splitable(was, sen, 1))  # False
<br/><br/>
# Should be False, since maximum word count wouldn't be possible
# between words 'find' and 'cat', where 'cat' is not even in sentence
print(check_splitable(was, 'please find', 1)) # True```

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to put newline in a comment? Thanks.

Comment: @Harsh quote them with \`\`\`, like codes

Comment: @Jimmy James yeah, Harsh is right, this solution is incorrect. For a certain word, the first one we meet in sentence should not always be chosen. Greedy algorithm leads to bad result.

An example: "please a find find a a cat" where the count limit is 2. Should return True, but my alg returns False.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228030/discussion-between-nathan-hardy-and-harsh).

Comment: Thanks @NathanHardy. I found this failed - text = "customer ethical"
        sentence = "oh right another customer very ethical"
        n = 2.

Comment: @JiminyJames I'm sorry I don't get it. text = "customer ethical", sentence = "oh right another customer very ethical", n=2 should return False and the func does return False. There are 3 words before "customer" and 3 > 2.

Comment: Hi @NathanHardy. Thanks for putting time into this, it's really appreciated when people respond to a question. For this question, the 'n' value is considered between the words in the 'word list'. The number of words that come before the first word from the 'word list' can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the words of the sentence and find whether the current word matches the next one in the `words` sequence. If so, then remove it from the `words` sequence, record the index. Finally, find the difference between the indices and check whether all values fall below or equal to 2.

```
def get_fuzziness(words, sentence_words):
    remaining_words = words.copy()
    indices = []
    num_words = len(words)
    for idx, expr in enumerate(sentence_words):
        if expr == remaining_words[0]:
            indices.append(idx)
            remaining_words.pop(0)

    if len(indices) != num_words:
        return False  # not all words found

    diff = _get_distances(indices)
    return all(i <= 2 for i in diff)


def _get_distances(indices):
    return [
        second - first
        for first, second in
        zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])
    ]


words = ['please', 'find', 'cat']
sentence = 'can you please find my cat'.split()
print(get_fuzziness(words, sentence))

sentence = 'can you please find my pretty cat'.split()
print(get_fuzziness(words, sentence))

sentence = 'find my cat please'.split()
print(get_fuzziness(words, sentence))
```

Output

```
True
False
False
```